# Find all modules that adopted behavior

Tags: elixir

Is it possible to find each loaded module that have adopted certain behavior?

I'm building a very simple chat Bot and I want to make some cool commands, but to achieve that i need a way to implement multiple commands, preferably without hardcoding them.

Each command would be a function that takes three params (message, author, chat_channel_ref) and returns true or false whether it matched and does something.

When i browsing through the Elixir tutorial i found [Behaviors](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/typespecs-and-behaviours.html#behaviours) which may nicely suit my needs if i could found all modules that have adopted them. Have anyone of you did it before? What else could i do? I also thought about "use" (in use i would execute code to add current module to a list held by agent).

Comment: How many of these are you going to have? Maybe it's simpler to just keep a list of them somewhere in your source code, maybe in a supervisor spec and then each one runs in a separate process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an excerpt from my exrm project, which does basically exactly that: it finds any module which implements the plugin behaviour:

```
  @doc """
  Loads all plugins in all code paths.
  """
  @spec load_all() :: [] | [atom]
  def load_all, do: get_plugins(ReleaseManager.Plugin)

  # Loads all modules that extend a given module in the current code path.
  @spec get_plugins(atom) :: [] | [atom]
  defp get_plugins(plugin_type) when is_atom(plugin_type) do
    available_modules(plugin_type) |> Enum.reduce([], &load_plugin/2)
  end

  defp load_plugin(module, modules) do
    if Code.ensure_loaded?(module), do: [module | modules], else: modules
  end

  defp available_modules(plugin_type) do
    # Ensure the current projects code path is loaded
    Mix.Task.run("loadpaths", [])
    # Fetch all .beam files
    Path.wildcard(Path.join([Mix.Project.build_path, "**/ebin/**/*.beam"]))
    # Parse the BEAM for behaviour implementations
    |> Stream.map(fn path ->
      {:ok, {mod, chunks}} = :beam_lib.chunks('#{path}', [:attributes])
      {mod, get_in(chunks, [:attributes, :behaviour])}
    end)
    # Filter out behaviours we don't care about and duplicates
    |> Stream.filter(fn {_mod, behaviours} -> is_list(behaviours) && plugin_type in behaviours end)
    |> Enum.uniq
    |> Enum.map(fn {module, _} -> module end)
  end
```

Comment: So it's runtime only?

Comment: You could run the same code at compile-time too, though there may be some caveats to that (I haven't needed to do that) - in exrm's case that isn't necessary. You could also just cache the results the first time it's run by stashing them in the application environment. It really depends on how often it needs to be called.

Comment: I tried this approach at runtime and at compile time. In both cases, I had issues between dev/test and prod environment. 
For my use case, I decided to go with a simple configuration, thus when I write a new module I simply add it to `config/config.ex` and read the list with `Application.get_env`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to consider which is similar to Behaviours is [Protocols](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/protocols.html) .  Make a protocol and then each new command must implement that protocol.

Comment: Yeah i thought about. But protocols are implemented per typr (for: lists etc.) And here aignature of each function will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library that only loads plugins if they support a specific 
function call. Behaviors are depreciated in Elixir, @behaviour in the Erlang way is still supported, but buys you much less than you would expect. ( Basically only a compile time warning if you are missing a function signature ).

https://github.com/bbense/pluginator

Comment: That's too bad that it's deprecated.

Comment: The Behaviour "macro" in Elixir is deprecated in favor of just using @behaviour module attributes. The functionality is still there, just the Elixir wrapping was removed since it was decided that it didn't add anything useful enough to justify it.